# How to stop variable from changing value after the first time in a loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to get a variable to change only in the first iteration of a loop unless another condition makes it so it needs a different value. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations; i++){
   if (this happens){
   value = i;  //trying to save that particular position
   }

//Now the problem is: the value will change in the next iteration.
```

¿How do I stop it without stopping the loop?

Comment: Do you wish to stop the loop completely after `value` is set?  Perhaps `break;` is the command you want?  Otherwise, to keep the loop running, but not change `value` again likely needs a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations; i++){
   if (this happens && i == 0) {  //that means if i is equal to 0 and your condition is true, code will be executed
       value = i;  //trying to save that particular position
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool setValue = true;  

for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations; i++){
   if (this happens && setValue){
       value = i;  //trying to save that particular position
       setValue = false; // Now that setValue is false
                         // variable "value" will not be set again,
                         // even if "this happens" is true
   } // End of if
} // End of For-loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be

```c
for (int i = 0; i < numOfIterations; i++){
   if (this happens && i == 0){
   value = i;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as another answer but with no explanation of what the code does.